# Row scroll not working with SingleChildScrollView or ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to do a simple scroll of a row. I tried `SingleChildScrollView` and `ListView` with the property of `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`, but I didn't find the reason why is not working.

Error

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 196 pixels on the right.

Parent

```js
class HotThisWeek extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Hot this week', style: kBigBoldText),
        const SizedBox(height: kCommonSeparation),
        HotThisWeekPostPreview()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Child

```js
class HotThisWeekPostPreview extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map> hotBackgrounds = [
      {
        'backgroundImage':
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577644036183-94ce86392140?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1236&q=80',
        'song': 'Call me never',
        'profileName': 'Courtney Nguyen'
      },
      {
        'backgroundImage':
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546934469-0659d570f44e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80',
        'song': 'Black in the dark',
        'profileName': 'Wade Richards'
      },
      {
        'backgroundImage':
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577644036183-94ce86392140?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1236&q=80',
        'song': 'Call me never',
        'profileName': 'Courtney Nguyen'
      },
    ];
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: buildHotThisWeekPostPreview(hotBackgrounds),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Padding> buildHotThisWeekPostPreview(List<Map> hotBackgrounds) {
    List<Padding> widgets = [];

    hotBackgrounds.forEach((hot) {
      widgets.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: kMediumSeparation),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          BackgroundImage(
            backgroundImage: hot['backgroundImage'],
            height: kSizePhotoHotThisWeek,
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 10,
            bottom: 40,
            child: Container(
              width: kSizePhotoHotThisWeek - 15,
              child: Text(
                hot['song'],
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: kMediumWhiteBoldText,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 10,
            bottom: 15,
            child: Container(
              width: kSizePhotoHotThisWeek - 15,
              child: Text(
                hot['profileName'],
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ));
    });
    return widgets;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: why use row when u can use listview builder with scrolling property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected reason is that the parent of my parent shown in this post has a Row, and for whatever reason, the scroll is only allowed in the first one, and in the second row is ignored.